# What is .1 file do in the Object-C programming?

Tags: objective-c

I am newbie to Object-C programming. After trying the very simple code, I found a *.1 file is generated. what is this file mean?

Answer (score 2):

`.1` is the file extension for the man page of a general user command—also used are `.2` through `.8`. This is not specific to Objective-C; see more info [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/man).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you created a project using the template OS X application > Command Line Tool. That file is a manual page for your application in troff format. You can read it with `nroff -man nameOfTheFile.1`.
At this point, just ignore it. If you want to write your own, see https://serverfault.com/a/109559/102042
For more info on man pages, check Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page